# How to load images from a folder into pandas with class name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a folder which comprises of different images like dell_01.png, hp_01.png, toshiba_01.png and would like to create a dataframe from it which would look like this:

If the file starts with hp, it should be assigned to class 1. If it starts with toshiba, it should be assigned to class 1. If it starts with dell, it should be assigned to class 2 as seen in the below expected dataframe output.

```
filename     class
hp_01.png        0
toshiba_01.png   1
dell_01.png      2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break the problem up:

> I have a folder... different images

So you need to get the filenames from the folder.  User `pathlib.Path.glob`:

```py
from pathlib import Path
for fn in Path("/path/to/folder/").glob("*.png"):
   ...
```

> if the file starts with `hp`... class 1, `toshiba`... class 2
> so you have a condition.

```py
if fn.stem.startswith("hp"):
    class = 1
elif ...
```

Now you can solve the two parts individually.

> in a dataframe

Use the two constructs above to make a *dictionary* for every file.  Then make a dataframe from that dict.  Your code will look something like this:

```py
files = []
for fn in Path("/path/to/pngs").glob("*.png"):
    if fn.stem.startwith("hp"):
        class = 0
    ...
    files.append({"filename": fn.name, "class": class})
```

(Yes, there are more direct routes to getting this into a dataframe, but I was trying to make what was going on clearer.)

Does that help?  I've deliberately avoided just writing the answer for you, but tried to get *just* close enough you can fill in the rest.

Comment: I admit the question shows no attempted solution.  But sometimes people are just stuck.